# Why Is My Implementation Of HashMap Much, Much, Slower Than Java's HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I made my own implementation of Java's `HashMap` after looking at the source code and watching a fiew videos on it. I only added the key methods, and this is what I came up with:

```
public class MyHashMap {

    private Node[] arr;
    private int n;

    public MyHashMap() {
        n = 16;
        arr = new Node[n];
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        int index = key & (n - 1);

        if (arr[index] == null) {
            arr[index] = new Node(key, value);
        } else {
            Node node = arr[index];

            if(node.key == key) {
                node.value = value;
                return;
            }

            while (node.next != null) {
                if(node.key == key) {
                    node.value = value;
                    return;
                }

                node = node.next;
            }

            node.next = new Node(key, value);
        }
    }

    public int get(int key) {
        int index = key & (n - 1);

        if(arr[index] == null) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            Node node = arr[index];

            while(node != null) {
                if(node.key == key) {
                    return node.value;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void remove(int key) {
        int index = key & (n - 1);

        if(arr[index] == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            Node node = arr[index];

            if(node.next == null && node.key == key) {
                arr[index] = null;
                return;
            }    

            while(node.next != null) {
                if(node.key == key) {
                    node.next = node.next.next;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class Node {
        int key, value;
        Node next;

        Node(int key, int value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }    

}
```

I can do relatively small commands without it taking to long, like this:

```
MyHashMap hashMap = new MyHashMap();
hashMap.put(1, 1);
hashMap.put(2, 2);
System.out.println(hashMap.get(1));            // returns 1
System.out.println(hashMap.get(3));            // returns -1 (not found)
hashMap.put(2, 1);          // update the existing value
System.out.println(hashMap.get(2));            // returns 1
hashMap.remove(2);          // remove the mapping for 2
System.out.println(hashMap.get(2));            // returns -1 (not found)
```

But as soon as I do more things, it takes a much longer time. I tried to see if Java's `HashMap` was as slow, but it took barely any time. What makes my implementation so much slower? It's not just a few milliseconds, it's about 5 seconds slower when my commands aren't even that much.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, Java doesn't have an implementation of anything: it's a language specification for which there are several implementations. But if you're referring to openjdk, the simple answer is that the hashmap algorithm is very sophisticated: it includes auto-expansion and either trees or linked lists on clashing hashes depending on size. It's over 2000 lines of code and has been heavily tailored over the years to balance memory and processor efficiency. There's no 1 simple explanation for why it's better.

Comment: Define 'more'. With such a tiny array size as 16 you will cease hashing and start linear searching as soon as `N > 16`, if not sooner. Try a realistic size like 32K.